# How to Add Flattened Layer (or Similar) For Variable Input Size of a Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am wondering if it is possible how to add a similar to flattened layer for images of variable length.

Say we have an input layer for our CNN as:

```
input_shape=(1, None, None)
```

After performing your typical series of convolution/maxpooling layers, can we create a flattened layer, such that the shape is:

```
output_shape=(None,...)
```

If not, would someone be able to explain why not?

Comment: Why do you want to flatten the layer?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `GlobalMaxPooling2D` and `GlobalAveragePooling2D`.

These will eliminate the spatial dimensions and keep only the channels dimension. `Max` will take the maximum values, `Average` will get the mean value.

I don't really know why you can't use a `Flatten` layer, but in fact you can't with variable dimensions.

I understand why a `Dense` wouldn't work: it would have a variable number of parameters, which is totally infeasible for backpropagation, weight update and things like that. (PS: Dense layers act only on the last dimension, so that is the only that needs to be fixed).

Examples:

- A Dense layer requires the last dimension fixed
- A Conv layer can have variable spatial dimensions, but needs fixed channels (otherwise the number of parameters will vary)
- A recurrent layer can have variable time steps, but needs fixed features and so on

Also, notice that:

- For classification models, you'd need a fixed dimension output, so, how to flatten and still guarantee the correct number of elements in each dimension? It's impossible.
- For models with variable output, why would you want to have a fixed dimension in the middle of the model anyway?

If you're going totally custom, you can always use `K.reshape()` inside a `Lambda` layer and work with the tensor shapes:

```
import keras.backend as K

def myReshape(x):

    shape = K.shape(x)
    batchSize = shape[:1]
    newShape = K.variable([-1],dtype='int32')
    newShape = K.concatenate([batchSize,newShape])

    return K.reshape(x,newShape)

The layer: Lambda(myReshape)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can because the compile step uses those dimensions to allocate fixed memory when your model is instanced for training or prediction.  Some dimensions need to be known ahead of time, so the matrix dimensions can be allocated.

I understand why you want variable-sized image input, the world is not (226, 226, 3).  It depends on your specific goals, but for me, scaling up or windowing to a region of interest using say Single Shot Detection as a preprocessing step may be helpful.  You could just start with Keras's ImageDataGenerator to scale all images to a fixed size - then you see how much of a performance gain you get from conditional input sizing or windowing preprocessing.

@mikkola, I have found flatten to be very helpful for TimeDistributed models.  You can add flatten after the convolution steps using:

```
your_model.add(Flatten())
```